# It's all fun and games

Tags: word-property

You're watching your favorite late night talk show, and the host Lavid Detterman is interviewing Kandy Offman. You have closed captions on, the text of which is shown below. The interview is, as you might have guessed, hilarious chaos. What's the cause of the misunderstanding?

> Lavid: ...it's all fun and games until someone loses an eye.
>
> Kandy: Someone doesn't have an eye.
>
> Lavid: What? How can you say that? You have two eyes.
>
> Kandy: You doesn't have any eyes.
>
> Lavid: I was talking about you not me.
>
> Kandy: I only has one eye. Me doesn't have any.
>
> Lavid: Ok, I'll play along with your delusion. What about spiders. How many eyes do spiders have?
>
> Kandy: One
>
> Lavid: And birds?
>
> Kandy: Only one
>
> Lavid: Dogs?
>
> Kandy: None
>
> Lavid: Cats?
>
> Kandy: Still none
>
> Lavid: Pigs?
>
> Kandy: One
>
> Lavid: Unicorns?
>
> Kandy: One
>
> Lavid: What about inanimate objects--let's get more abstract, say oh I don't know--Wikipedia?
>
> Kandy: Wikipedia has three eyes.
>
> Lavid: Oh it does does it?
>
> Kandy: No it only has one eye.
>
> Lavid: But you said...

Why is the interview going so hilariously wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because

> Kandy is talking about the letter "i" and how many are in the word.  For instance spider has one i.  Lavid is talking about eyes.  Hilarity ensues.